# Writing $\forall q\, (\forall p\,q)$ instead of the schematic $\forall p\,\phi$

Tags: logic, quantifiers, second-order-logic

Suppose we're working with the propositional logic enriched with propositional quantifiers. Is it, in general, all right to write $\forall q\, (\forall p\,q)$ instead of the schematic $\forall p\,\phi$? Consider, for example, the Universal Instantiation rule: $\forall\!p\,\phi\to\phi[\psi/p]$. Would it be grammatical to turn this schematic axiom into something like this: $\forall q\forall r\, ((\forall p q)\to q[r/p])$?

Answer (score 3):

With the usual definitions, this won't work. The difficulty is that, unlike $\phi$, which can contain occurrences of $p$ for you to replace with $\psi$, the propositional variable $q$ doesn't contain any occurrence of $p$ for you to replace with $r$.

It *might* be possible to invent some new notion of substitution to make this idea work, but I don't see a reasonable way to do that (and I'm quite skeptical about the possibility).

Comment: Thanks! I can see that the problem here is in particular with the notion of substitution. What about in the following case? Suppose (for the sake of argument) that we have an schematic axiom of the form $\forall\!p\,(p\to\forall\!q \,\phi)$. Can we instead write $\forall\!p\forall\!r\,(p\to\forall\!q \,r)$?